# OWASP ESAPI XSS Attack undetected

Tags: javascript, java, security, xss, esapi

In a web project we use ESAPI validator to detect XSS attacks using antisamy XML file. While most of the attacks are detected as expected, it fails to detect the below given input as an XSS attack.

**<img src=x onerror=alert(1) alt=**

Potentially, the browser closes the  tag itself, hence triggering the alert function.

Surprisingly, ESAPI detects the below given input as an XSS attack:

**<img src=x onerror=alert(1) alt="text"**

The backend has been written in Java and the UI in JavaScript.
Antisamy file used:

https://github.com/OWASP/EJSF/blob/master/esapi_master_FULL/antisamy-esapi.xml

I also tried using the myspace antisamy file, but the problem still persists.

Can someone please help me with the reason for the difference in behavior or how to mitigate the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Just being curious here, why do you need to look for XSS injections inside your web application ? Can't you just properly escape the content you insert into the DOM ?

Comment: @ShellCode we need to fetch & use the data from the DOM which would come altered in case we escape. Example: original data is 5 < 9. After escaping we'll get 5 &lt; 9. So i'll have to unescape everywhere while fetching the data from DOM. Also, a good approach is to prevent data saving.

Comment: Since this might be a bug a better place to ask this would be at the ESAPI github:  github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy.  In short, @ShellCode's onto the right idea:  input validation is never considered a 100% solution, output encoding is.  Here's several hundred reasons why:  https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet

Comment: Probably not a bug, just a regex that doesn't cover all edge cases (because there's no way to do so). @AmanTodi I hope you realize there's **no way** to prevent 100% XSS injections by filtering them out like you're trying to do. The **only way** to make your app free of XSS is escaping.

Comment: @ShellCode I agree that this probably isn't a bug, but (since I'm the co-lead) on ESAPI I'd rather take that time to make sure of it.

Comment: @avgvstvs I have updated the regex to [a-zA-Z0-9\:\-_\.]+ for alt tag such that it needs minimum one character. Below are the obervations:
1. Input: <img src=x alt="" || Observation: Tag is filtered || Status: Passed
2. Input: <img src=x alt= || Observation: Tag not filtered || Status: Failed
3. Input: <img src=x onerror=alert(1) alt="" || Observation: Tag is filtered (due to regex condition for onerror) || Status: Passed
4. Input: <img src=x onerror=alert(1) alt= || Observation: Tag not filtered || Status: Failed

Comment: Somehow it seems to me that validation of onerror attribute changes if the value of alt attribute is not supplied. FYI, I have seen a similar case with button tag as well..

Comment: You can update the regex to require a minimum of one character, but that's unique to your application.  It's entirely possible to have empty attributes.  I'd recommend testing that regex as a unit test in the ESAPI library to ensure changing that regex doesn't cause an error somewhere you're not looking.

Answer (score 0):

It also would help for us to know which version of ESAPI you were testing this with as different versions use different versions of AntiSamy. (In fact, there is a new 1.6.0 version coming out shortly, after which we expect to release a new ESAPI point release.)
But knowing the ESAPI version (or more specifically, the AntiSamy version) would allow us to make sure that this isn't a bug in AntiSamy.

Comment: I am using esapi-2.1.0.1 and antisamy-1.5.3 jars.

Comment: Update, I upgraded the antisamy jar to 1.5.7 and the behavior is same. Instead of thinking it to be bug, can you please help me with the probable reasons which could cause such behavior please?

Comment: I will reply over on https://github.com/nahsra/antisamy/issues/69 where you created an issue and just link that back to here. But I would strongly suggest that you upgrade to the latest ESAPI release (2.2.2.0) and the latest AntiSamy release (1.5.13) or at least create a mini-test and see if that combination fixes your problems. Once AntiSamy 1.6.0 comes out, I plan on doing a new ESAPI release.

Comment: Also, did you find anything of interest in the AntiSamy or ESAPI logs? I'm thinking perhaps the XML parser that AntiSamy used might have thrown an exception.